# customize boundary character in regex

Tags: java, regex, word-boundary

I have found that `\b` is used for capturing boundary characters in regex.

Like with regex `\bnull\b` and input `,null,` it will capture `null` and with input `.null.` it will also capture `null`

What I want is to tell `\b` that it should only capture null of `,null,` input and it should not consider null of `-null-` `.null.` etc

How can i do this?

Comment: Could you provide some examples for better understanding?

Comment: /bnull/b matches whole word "null"
in any delimiter 
I want to customize it in way like it should only capture .null. or it should only capture ,null, not all cases

Comment: @Keppil i am getting a csv file and replacing null with empty spaces
If i use the expression you provided it will not handle null,raheel,email
or raheel,email,null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Updating my answer, due to added information from your comment above. Please try to give all necessary information to understand the problem when asking questions.

To match the nulls in `null,raheel,email`, `raheel,email,null` and `,null,` while not matching `null` with any other adjacent character than comma, you can use:

```
(?:^|,)null(?:,|$)
```

See for yourself [here](http://regexr.com?31s5t).

**Another update:** New info again...

To also match the nulls in `null,null,null`, you can use:

```
(?<=,|^)null(?=,|$)
```

See for yourself [here](http://regexr.com?31s60).

Comment: Its working for some cases only i got a solution
 (?<=(;))null(?=(;|$))
if i give input null;null;null
It captures 2nd and 3rd null
to capture first null i also used
 (?<=(^))null(?=(;|$)) |  (?<=(;))null(?=(;|$))
But it costs performance issue
and  (?<=(;|^))null(?=(;|$)) does not work, can you tell me why its not working

Comment: Hm, I don't know - somehow the nested groups seem to cause a problem. Check out my updated answer, does this do the trick now?